# Iterate through hash values in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I've got a hash with let's say 20 values.

It's initialized this way:

```
my $line = $_[0]->[0];

    foreach my $value ($line) {
        print $value;
    }
```

Now when I try to get the value of each hash in $line it says:
Use of uninitialized value in print at file.pl line 89

Is there a way to iterate through each value of a hash?

I also tried it with:

```
my %line = $_[0]->[0];

    foreach my $key (keys %line) {
        print %line->{$key};
    }
```

But that is also not working:
Reference found where even-sized list expected at file.pl at line 89

Anybody knows what to do? It shouldn't be that difficult...

Comment: I'm confused. Sure looks to me like you've initialized a scalar, not a hash.

Comment: And in your second example, you're trying to make it a hash, but you're still assigning a scalar - maybe it's a hash ref?

Comment: Use the Perl debugger and print out your arglist using the `x` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$line` in your first example is a scalar, not a hash.

If it's a hash reference, dereference it with `%{$line}`.

Comment: Ah I see! Now it's working with:

my $line = $_[0]->[0];
 
 foreach my $value (values %{$line}) {
  print $value . "\n";
 }

Answer (score 12):

To iterate over values in a hash:

```
for my $value (values %hash) {
  print $value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you must understand the difference between a hash, and a hash reference.

Your initial assignment `$_[0]->[0]` means something like : Takes the first argument of the current function (`$_[0]`), dereference it (`->`) and consider it is an array and retrieves it's first value (`[0]`). That value can not be a list or a hash, it must be a scalar (string, int, float, reference).

Here is some example:

```
my %hash = ( MyKey => "MyValue");
my $hashref = \%hash;
# The next line print all elements of %hash
foreach (keys %hash) { print $_ }
# And is equivalent to
foreach (keys %{$hashref}) { print $_ }
$hash{MyKey} == $hashref->{MyKey}; # is true
```

Please refer to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html for further details.

Comment: No, `$_[0]` is not a function. It’s the first (scalar) element of `@_`.  So `$_[0]->[0]` — which is the same as `$_[0][0]` and `${ $_[0] }[0]` — takes that first scalar element of `@_`, construes it to be a reference to an array, and returns the first element of that putatively referenced array.

Comment: Never said that $_[0] was a function.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is telling you that there *nothing* at `$_[0]->[0]`. It's not dying and telling you that you're indexing nothing, so `$_[0]` is likely an arrayref, but nothing is in the first slot--or perhaps it's pointing to an empty array.

- Were it a empty string or a 0, it wouldn't complain.
- Were there any reference there, you could print something even if only: `BLAH(0x80af74)`. (Where "BLAH" is one of "ARRAY", "HASH", "SCALAR", "REF", "GLOB", "IO", ... )

My suggestion is that you do this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $_[0] ] ); # or even say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@_ ] )
```

and then look at the output.

Once you've got a hashref at `$_[0]->[0]`, then if you must loop through the hash, the best way is:

```
while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each %$hashref ) { 
   do_stuff_with_key_and_value( $key, $value );
}
```

see [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)

Lastly, it seems that you have some sigil confusion. See the last part of this link for a decent attempt to explain that sigils ( `'$'`, `'@'`, `'%'` ) are *not* part of the name of a variable, but indicators what we want retrieved from it. [Perl compilation woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083836/perl-compilation-woes/4083869#answer-4083869)